# Same action triggering in multiple slices Redux-Toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

I seem to be missing something. I have the following setup:

projectSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const projectSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'projects',
  initialState: {
    list: {
      'project-1': {
        id,
        columnIds: [columnId1, columnId2, ...],
        ...
      }
    },
    order: [],
  },
  reducers: {
     ...
  },
  extraReducers: {
    'columns/createColumn': (state, action) => {
      // this never triggers
      const { payload: { projectId, column } = action
      state.list[projectId].columnIds.splice(0, 0, column.id)
    }
  }
})
export default projectSlice.reducer
```

columnSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const columnSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'columns',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    createColumn(state, action) {
       ...
    }
  },
})
export const { createColumn } = columnSlice.actions
export default columnSlice.reducer
```

and store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import projectReducer from '../projectSlice'
import columnSlice from '../columnSlice'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    projects: projectReducer,
    columns: columnReducer,
  }
})
```

Now, from what I understand from the docs, extraReducer should be able to listen to other redux actions, and trigger the extraReducer action.

I simplified this example, but basically I have a slice for columns and a slice for projects, and whenever a column is created, I need to add that to the list of columns in the project slice. But the extraReducer is never triggering. Not really sure where to go from here.

## EDIT

Forgot to include this before, the dispatch is triggered from a react component

Project.js

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { createColumn } from '../../columnSlice'

export default function Project() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(createColumn({...})
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
  )
}
```

The dispatch only triggers for the columnSlice, not for projectSlice

An example is provided [in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-extrareducer-example-4b9oc) to illustrate the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should export `createColumn` action creator from `columnSlice.actions`. Then you need to dispatch the action that `createColumn` created.

E.g.

`columnSlice.ts`:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const columnSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'columns',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    createColumn(state, action) {
      console.log('[columnSlice]: ', action);
    },
  },
});


export const { createColumn } = columnSlice.actions;

export default columnSlice.reducer;
```

`projectSlice.ts`:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const projectSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'projects',
  initialState: {
    list: {
      'project-1': {
        id: 1,
        columnIds: [1, 2],
      },
    },
    order: [],
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    'columns/createColumn': (state: any, action) => {
      console.log('[projectSlice]:', action);
    },
  },
});
export default projectSlice.reducer;
```

`store.ts`:

```
import projectReducer from './projectSlice';
import columnReducer, { createColumn } from './columnSlice';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    projects: projectReducer,
    columns: columnReducer,
  },
});

store.dispatch(createColumn({}));
```

Output in the console:

```
[projectSlice]: { type: 'columns/createColumn', payload: {} }
[columnSlice]:  { type: 'columns/createColumn', payload: {} }
```

As you can see, both reducers are triggered.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually exporting createColumn from the columnSlice, just forgot to add that in the question. I edited the question. It only seems to be triggering in columnSlice, any other thoughts?

Comment: This worked. I spent hours on this and the entire issue was ```extraReducer``` vs ```extraReducers``` ... ouch

Comment: @JoshuaRichardson TypeScript can help you avoid this spelling mistake

Comment: I would add to use imported action converted to string instead of typed manually. `${createColumn}`